# Find sentence and paragraph with Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sentence

I have following format of data:

```
[1956, Jon's story, He sold his soul in 1987, 200]  
[1960, Mary's story, "She liked her soul, but decided to sold it anyway.", 250]  
[1963, "Alice and Peter story, with a twist", "Peter said "Your soul is mine!" and tried to sold it, but Alice had no soul and killed him.", 500]
```

I want to split this to

```
[1956, 1960, 1963]  
['Jon's story', 'Mary's story','Alice and Peter story, with a twist']  
['He sold his soul in 1987','She liked her soul, but decided to sold it anyway.','Peter said "Your soul is mine!" and tried to sold it, but Alice had no soul and killed him.']  
[200,250,500]
```

So far I've done this

```
import re
data = [[1956, "Jon's story", "He sold his soul in 1987", 200],
        [1960, "Mary's story", "She liked her soul, but decided to sold it anyway.", 250],
        [1963, "Alice and Peter story, with a twist", "Peter said 'Your soul is mine!' and tried to sold it, but Alice had no soul and killed him.", 500]]
for row in data:
    line = str(row)
    sentence = re.split(r',', line)
```

But this way it takes into account comma separation inside " ". How can I avoid it?

Comment: Are you after `list(zip(*data))`?

Comment: From your question I could deduce that you want each first, second, third and fourth element from each list returned as 4 separate lists. Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Elements are separated by comma and "".

Comment: It is not after list(zip(*data)). It is actually csv, but all standart procedures with csv (as delimiter=',', read csv by pandas and ect) didn't work, for some reason it assumed that I have only 1 line (I guess because comma inside ""). So I decided to do loop and do it line by line.

Comment: Hard to follow since the initial data is formatted incorrectly, If you want to do it raw from a csv, you could add the snipped of the csv and add the pandas tag

Answer (score 0):

So this can be solved by using zip instead of re, look below at the code and see how it works. m4,m3,m2,m1 will be the lists with the values you needed

```
    data = [[1956, "Jon's story", "He sold his soul in 1987", 200],
    [1960, "Mary's story", "She liked her soul, but decided to sold it anyway.", 250],
    [1963, "Alice and Peter story, with a twist", "Peter said 'Your soul is mine!' and tried to sold it, but Alice had no soul and killed him.", 500]]
    m4, m3 ,m2,m1 = map(list, zip(*data))
```